# Don't have delete button when swipe on table row

Tags: ios, swift

I create new project,
Then add TableView to ViewController, set dataSource and delegate to View Controller,
Add one prototype cell with Basic style and identifier "cell".
My  ViewController.swift class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate{

    var numbers = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numbers.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell
        cell?.textLabel.text = numbers[indexPath.row]

        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            numbers.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        }
    }

}
```

When I swipe row, it moving but delete button is missing.
Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replicated your project. Delete button is there.

[image]

You should check the constraints of your table view to make sure it does not inadvertently extend beyond the right edge of the screen.